# How to connect to a nested VM running on GCE instance directly from the internet

Tags: networking, virtualization, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, virtual-network

I have a nested VM running on a Google Cloud instance for the purpose of providing access to a legacy application in a redundant environment. Networking is working between the host and guest, and between another instance on the same VPC and guest, using an IP alias and iptables as per Google's documentation. However, I need to be able to connect directly to the guest from the internet. I have tried using a forwarding rule to map an additional external IP, but there doesn't seem to be a way to point it to the IP alias, only the instance as a whole. How can I map an external IP to the nested VM so I can access any service on it (not just HTTP/S)? Thanks in advance for any insight.